# Matlab : Erasing values from text file

Tags: matlab, text-processing

I have a text file like this:

```
1st col  2nd col 

    20   8
    300  9
    31   5
    20   7
    20   7
    300  8
```

There is a long list of such numbers in a text file. I have to do two things with this file:

All those numbers in first column which are occuring  less than ten times. Those all rows should be removed from the text file.

In the end, I should get a file with those entries omitted.

How can I achieve the above goal in Matlab or which function can help me in this regard?

This code , I tried:

```
data = importdata('check.txt'); 
data(data(:,1)<3,:)=[];

datacell = cellstr(num2str(data));

fileID = fopen('newfile.txt','w');
for k = 1:size(datacell,1)
    fprintf(fileID,'%s\n',datacell{k,:});
end
fclose(fileID);
```

**check.txt:**

```
32 7
32 7
32 7
6 9
32 7
32 7
56 7
6 87
```

**newfile.txt:**  (output file)

```
32   7
32   7
32   7
 6   9
32   7
32   7
56   7
 6  87
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use [**`importdata`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) -

```
data = importdata(filepath1) %%// filepath1 is the path to the text file

num_occ = 3; %%// Minimum limit to no. of occurances for data to be kept

unqvals = unique(data(:,1))
data = data(~ismember(data(:,1),unqvals(histc(data(:,1),unqvals)<num_occ)),:)

datacell = cellstr(num2str(data));

fileID = fopen(filepath1,'w');
for k = 1:size(datacell,1)
    fprintf(fileID,'%s\n',datacell{k,:});
end
fclose(fileID);
```

Please remember that it will over-write data into the input file, as asked in comments.

Comment: Will this write the new data to the same file? I am doing this but no changes in the text file.

Comment: Do you have any data less than 10 in the first column? Also could you report back the output from `whos data`?

Comment: I have added the code in my post with output. SInce my original file was large so I tried it on small file.

Comment: It must not work and it's not because you have `3` there in - `data(data(:,1)<3,:)=[];` and you have no data less than `3` in your sample.

Comment: 3 basically corresponds to the number of times a unique value in 1st column repeats. Eg, in above case 56 and 6 are the two values which are apearing one and two times respectively. So, they should be removed from the original data.

Comment: In your original question you said "All those numbers in first column which are less than ten". In my code I had `10` for that - `data(data(:,1)<10,:)=[];`. I am failing to understand your new requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I checked my question again, it made a wrong sense. I should have written that the frequency of the number appearing in first column should be less than ten.

Comment: @Zara Check out edited code. Please remember that it will over-write into the input file as you were asking for it in your comments.